# Undefined control sequence \subfloat

Tags: subfloats

This is odd, my code was working just fine, then I literally just step out of the room and when I come back and compile I get the error undefined control sequence \subfloat.

Basically I am trying to arrange 3 images, cc.png, bb.png and tt.png in a document side by side rather than in a column as latex was trying to make it. This is the relevant section of my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{axodraw4j}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{color}

\DeclareMathSizes{10}{12}{10}{6}


\begin{document} 

\title{Higgs Boson Deacay} 
\author{name} 
\maketitle 


    \begin{figure}[h!t]
        \centering
        \subfloat{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{cc}}
        \subfloat{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{bb}}
        \subfloat{\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{tt}}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

My output was fine and I'm sure I didn't change anything (although I concede I must have done otherwise there would be no problem) but this code now keeps giving me the error I have stated. I've looked at this for so long that the problem is probably staring me in the face but I can't see it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I use `subfig` instead of `subfloat` in the package declaration, then the code goes as expected.

Comment: Thanks, this small change fixed the problem, that must be what I changed. Thanks for the other answers also. I will give subcaption a try.

Answer (score 32):

The `subfloat` package doesn't define `\subfloat` (and has never defined it). Its purpose is different: you can group different captions under the same number with a letter attached, similarly to what the environment `subequations` (from `amsmath`) does.

For `\subfloat` you need to load `subfig`

```
\usepackage{subfig}
```

or

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

if you don't want to load the `caption` package together with `subfig` (some classes, notably `IEEEtran` don't allow the loading of `caption`.

You should consider `subcaption`, though, if you don't have limitations on the packages you use: it's more recent and well maintained. Moreover it has not the small defects `subfig` shows when `hyperref` is used.

By the way you should not say

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
```

(where you place `!` is immaterial), but

```
\begin{figure}[!htp]
```

because otherwise you could block the float queue.

Answer (score 8):

Please don't use `subfloat`, `subfig` and friends, because those have certain issues with some document classes. Here is a solution using the recent `subcaption` package.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document} 
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{cc}
        \caption{cc}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hskip2em
    \begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{bb}
        \caption{bb}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{tt}
        \caption{tt}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Several subfigures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: Any time I see “`subfig` is deprecated” I ask: by whom? No, it isn't; a manual says it, but it's wrong. The package `subcaption` is certainly better, but some classes *do not* allow it, and the safety escape is `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`.

Comment: @egreg Sorry about that. Thanks for clearing that up. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use multiple subfigures.

For that you have to include the subcaption package declaration:

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

Then, the code for putting 3 figures side-by-side looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
           \centering
           \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1.png}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig2.png}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig3.png}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:c}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Three images side-by-side}
    \end{figure}
```