# Undefined control sequence \subfloat - using subcaption

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I get the same error as [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154811/undefined-control-sequence-subfloat), however I had already switched from the `subfig` package to `subcaption` a while back. I am trying to recompile a TeX file on Linux that was fine before on OS X.

So I find this in my class file:

```
% \usepackage{subfig} % --- this replaces subfigure 
\usepackage{subcaption} % --- this replaces subfig
```

I look into the `subcaption` documentation, and in §3.4.4 it does mention the `\subfloat` command.

Reading other Stackexchange posts on this, I gather that many people believe `subcaption` does *not* define `subfloat` while others insist they *do* get that command. My interpretation from this is that perhaps `subfloat` was part of a specific version of `subcaption` and maybe was removed later?

Comment: I see no section 3.4.4 in the documentation of `subcaption`; there's no `\subfloat` command for it, as far as I know. The `\subfloat` command is instead used by the `subfig` package. And there's no "old" and "new": `subfig` and `subcaption` are completely different packages.

Comment: As I guessed it has been removed. In the [older version v1.0b](ftp://mirrors.lunarpages.com/FreeBSD/ports/distfiles/latex-caption/subcaption.pdf), dated 2008/08/31 it is in §3.4.4, in the [last version on the net v1.1-68](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf), dated 2013/04/16, it is not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This old code…

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[sub-caption1]{
  \includegraphics{...}
  \label{fig:sub1}
}
\subfloat[sub-caption2]{
  \centering\includegraphics{...}
  \label{fig:sub2}
}
\caption{main caption}
\label{fig:main}
\end{figure}
```

…can be roughly rewritten as

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
  \centering\includegraphics{...}
  \caption{sub-caption1}\label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
  \centering\includegraphics{...}
  \caption{sub-caption2}\label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{main caption}
\label{fig:main}
\end{figure}
```

Note that you have to find suitable width parameters and use additional `\centering` commands, otherwise the captions are left-aligned now.