# Reference of subfloat not appearing in pdf

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

I'm trying to reference the subfloat using `\ref{img1}` and `\ref{img2}` but its not working, a `?` keeps appearing in the reference location. If anyone could please advise.

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.49\linewidth]{img1}}\label{img1}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.49\linewidth]{img2}}\label{img2}
\caption{The two methods a and b.} 
\label{fig:KC3}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `\label`s inside the brackets meant for sub captions like

```
\subfloat[\label{img1}]{....
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[t]
\subfloat[\label{img1}]{\includegraphics[width=.49\linewidth]{img1}}
\subfloat[\label{img2}]{\includegraphics[width=.49\linewidth]{img2}}
\caption{The two methods a and b.}
\label{fig:KC3}
\end{figure}
This is \ref{img1} and \ref{img2} but its not working
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*When a label is declared within a float environment, the \ref{...} will return the respective fig/table number, but it must occur **after** the caption*. [Wikipedia reference](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing)

I have never used subfloat before, but I had the same problem with figure and subfigure. This should fix it ;)

Second, I did some small research on subfloats and there are some strong disagreements to used it. I know *subfloat* is not your problem right now, but maybe good to look at how you could implemented it with other methods [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154811/undefined-control-sequence-subfloat)